# How can I get all the ancestors' methods in JS (prototypal inheritance)?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, methods, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I need to create a function in JS that gets all the methods from the whole inheritance tree so as to insert one `<button>` for each method. I have this code

```
function A () {
}

A.prototype.a = function () {
    console.log('a');
}

function B () {
    this.super = A;
    this.super();
}

B.prototype = new A;
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.b = function () {
    console.log('b');
}

function C () {
    this.super = B;
    this.super();
}

C.prototype = new B;
C.prototype.constructor = C;

C.prototype.c = function () {
    console.log('c');
}

function D () {
}

D.prototype = C;
D.prototype.constructor = D;

D.prototype.d = function () {
    console.log('d');
}

const dd = new D();
```

I need some way to find the methods of the whole tree in case I didn't know how many ancestors an object has. For example: If an object C had A and B as its ancestors, I need the methods from A, B, and C; If a D object were a child of A-B-C, I need the methods of them four (A, B, C, and D). I may be able to trace by hand each method so as to write a code that does that for me, buy I need it to be dynamic.

This is what I'm using:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dd.__proto__).filter(function (property) {
    return (
        typeof dd.__proto__[property] === 'function' && property !== 'constructor'
    );
}))
```

Comment: What is the exact output you expect for the example? Do you need to see the owner of the method? Any specific order?

Comment: Secondly, do you expect prototype functions to be listed that belong to `Object.prototype`?

Comment: Hi! In the code I wrote, the output is only the method of D. I don't need to see the owner of the method, and it doesn't matter the order. I don't need the methods of Object. If I change dd.__proto__ for dd.prototype, I get the method of C; If instead I write dd.prototype.__proto__, I get the method of B; to get the method of A I have to put dd.prototype.__proto__.__proto__. This makes the job kind of difficult to automatize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your setup-code:

Change:

```
D.prototype = C;
```

to:

```
D.prototype = new C;
```

Then to get the list of methods (even when not enumerable), make a recursive call. You can even make it a generator.

To make clear where the methods come from, I have prefixed them with the name of the prototype object (like `A.prototype`). You will see that when functions with the same name exist at multiple levels of the prototype chain, they get each listed:

```js
function * iterMethods(o) {
    if (!o || o === Object.prototype) return;
    for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
        try {
            if (name !== "constructor" && typeof o[name] === "function") {
                yield o.constructor.name + ".prototype." + name;
            }
        } catch {}
    }
    yield * iterMethods(Object.getPrototypeOf(o));
}

// Your code:
function A () {
}

A.prototype.a = function () {
    console.log('a');
}

function B () {
    this.super = A;
    this.super();
}

B.prototype = new A;
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.b = function () {
    console.log('b');
}

function C () {
    this.super = B;
    this.super();
}

C.prototype = new B;
C.prototype.constructor = C;

C.prototype.c = function () {
    console.log('c');
}

function D () {
}

D.prototype = new C;
D.prototype.constructor = D;

D.prototype.d = function () {
    console.log('d');
}

const dd = new D();

// The call:
console.log(Array.from(iterMethods(Object.getPrototypeOf(dd))));
```

It is easier to set up this prototypal hierarchy when you use the `class ... extends` syntax. I would also not define `super` as that is a keyword that is natively available. Here is how that would look:

```js
function * iterMethods(o) {
    if (!o || o === Object.prototype) return;
    for (let name of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o)) {
        try {
            if (name !== "constructor" && typeof o[name] === "function") {
                yield o.constructor.name + ".prototype." + name;
            }
        } catch {}
    }
    yield * iterMethods(Object.getPrototypeOf(o));
}

// class syntax version:
class A {
    a() {
        console.log('a');
    }
}

class B extends A {
    b() {
        console.log('b');
    }
}

class C extends B {
    c() {
        console.log('c');
    }
}

class D extends C {
    d() {
        console.log('d');
    }
}

const dd = new D();

// The call:
console.log(Array.from(iterMethods(Object.getPrototypeOf(dd))));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. That's exactly what I was looking for. The only thing I modified is the first ```yield``` so as to get only the method name.